# A topoplot function for Mathematica

Tags: plotting

Matlab's EEGlab toolbox has a topoplot function:

http://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/

A typical topographical plot of an EEG signal is given below:

[image]

How can I reproduce this in Mathematica. I know that ContourPlot and ListCountourPlot provide such functionalities, however, the data is on a square grid... and I would like it on a circle like in the figure...

Comment: Look at the documentation for ContourPlot, including clicking on Details and Options and also further down clicking on Options and then RegionFunction and reading all the fine print.

Comment: Related: [(27252)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27252/121)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) is the option you are looking for.

```
ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[Sum[Sin[RandomReal[5, 2].{x, y}], {5}]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Black},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 9]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Neat trick for generating a random function.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to `RegionFunction` is  `ConditionalExpression`. Using @paw's cool example

```
z = Sum[Sin[RandomReal[5, 2].{x, y}], {5}];
ContourPlot[Evaluate[ConditionalExpression[z,Norm[{x, y}, 2] < 3]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
            BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Black}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[ConditionalExpression[z, z Norm[{x, y}] < 3]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
            BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Black}]
```

[image]